# Error while Install web3.py. "python setup.py egg_info"

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

I am trying to install web3.py (pip install web3) and get this error:
"python setup.py egg_info" failed.

How can I fix this and install web3.py?

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\onlyd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\onlyd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ji347dtb\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\onlyd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ji347dtb\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\onlyd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ji347dtb\pycryptodome\
    Complete output (20 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\onlyd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ji347dtb\pycryptodome\setup.py", line 468, in <module>
        set_compiler_options(package_root, ext_modules)
      File "C:\Users\onlyd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ji347dtb\pycryptodome\compiler_opt.py", line 341, in set_compiler_options
        clang = compiler_is_clang()
      File "C:\Users\onlyd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ji347dtb\pycryptodome\compiler_opt.py", line 251, in compiler_is_clang
        return test_compilation(source, msg="clang")
      File "C:\Users\onlyd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ji347dtb\pycryptodome\compiler_opt.py", line 82, in test_compilation
        objects = compiler.compile([fname], extra_postargs=extra_cc_options)
      File "C:\Users\onlyd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 346, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "C:\Users\onlyd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 239, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "C:\Users\onlyd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "C:\Users\onlyd\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 271, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
        "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    Testing support for clang
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 2):

See this: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

You need a C compiler to install dependencies web3.py is using.